# How to JSON stringify a field in Angular formly?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-formly

I am displaying data on the field like so for teams. I have the correct data but it is shown as [object, Object]. How would I JSON.stringify this in the field key?

```
 public config = {
columns: [
  { field: 'name', label: 'Name' }, //I get the name just fine
  { field: 'age', label: 'age' }, // I get the age just fine
  { field: 'teams', label: 'Teams' }, // I get all the teams but 
                                      // [object, Object] is shown
],
}
```

Template

```
  <tr *ngFor="let item of items ">
  <td *ngFor="let column of config.columns">
    <span *ngIf="!column.click && !column.link">
      {{item[column.field] | json}}
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="column.link">
      <a [routerLink]="[item.id, column.link]">
        {{item[column.field] | json}}
      </a>
    </span>
  </td>

</tr>
```

How would I access the role value here.I get this data with the 'teams' field but I need to access role specifically.

```
[ { "programId": "feef40bb-c4a3-4185-9e89-162349acd9aad", "userId": "bab.admin", "role": "regionalManager", "id": "59408f47fd44df38a89db6e5", "created": "2017-06-14T01:20:07.273Z", "modified": "2017-06-14T01:20:07.273Z" }, { "programId": "fe2fa0bb-c3a3-4185-9e89-16779acd9aad", "userId": "bab.admin", "role": "salesManager", "id": "59408f47fd44df38a89db6e6", "created": "2017-06-14T01:20:07.275Z", "modified": "2017-06-14T01:20:07.275Z" }, ]
```

Comment: you can do like this {{config | json}}

Comment: Where? I'm using angular 4

Comment: in your html file.

Comment: That put everything into JSON literally. How would I display it in string format

Comment: I'm trying to access a specific property and value in teams

Comment: Show us your template...

Comment: the  {{item[column.field] | json}} puts " " on everything

Comment: I updated what property I was trying to access how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Okay, what is the connection between config and the array you are posting at the end of the question. How are these connected, I'm not really understanding you template based on this data :)

Comment: Is there anyway I could use .map within {{ }} I could access property like that

Comment: @mrtaz Well it's really hard for me to understand what you are trying to achieve here. I asked about the connection of these data, since I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you perhaps create a plunker that showcases a bit what you want to achieve and tell us what is not working and how you would like it to show in template.